# How to format an Angular Reactive Form Control value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

If I have an Angular Form Control as below, what would be the recommended way to format the value?

e.g. I could have a date field returned from the database with seconds and milliseconds etc. How can I format this is a similar way to the date pipe so I just show day, month, year etc?

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="date">
```

My typescript file would be as follows:

```
export class MyForm {

   form: FormGroup;

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.setupForm();

     this.httpService.get(5).subscribe((response) => {
       this.form.patchValue(response);
     });
   }

   setupForm(): void {
     this.form = new FormGroup({
       date: new FormControl('')
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to format the value when you create the control and assign the value in your FormGroup:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  date: new FormControl(datePipe.transform(yourData.date, yourFormat)),
});
```

If you need to populate your value from a service call, you can instantiate the form after the service call completes:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpService.get(5).subscribe((response) => {
    if (response) {
      this.setupForm(response);
    }
  });
}

setupForm(data): void {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(datePipe.transform(data.date, yourFormat)),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. How would that work when the record is return from a database? I've expanded my example a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: You would want to instantiate your form *after* your service call completes. If you're using the data other places, you could set a view model property on your class, or you could pass the data as an argument to `setupForm(data)`

Comment: There's no need to instantiate the form, then patch the values. It's much easier to just make your HTTP call, then instantiate the form after you get the data.

Comment: That is great. Thanks for your help.